# stop a loop from asking user input

Tags: java

problem here is that we want the program to stop the loop/stop asking integers when '-1' is inputted by the user that it wont have to get the maximum length of our array

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DELETE DUPLICATES {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInput();
        getCopies(maxInput);
        removeDuplicates(maxInput);
}
static int[] maxInput= new int[20];
static int[] copies = new int[20];
static int[] duplicate = new int[20];
//get user's input/s    
public static void UserInput() {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int integer = 0;
        int i = 0;
  System.out.println("Enter Numbers:  ");
        while(i < maxInput.length)
        {
                integer = scan.nextInt();         
                maxInput[i] = integer;
                        i++; 
                        if (integer == -1) 
                            break;  
        }
                  int j = 0;
        for(int allInteger : maxInput) {
                System.out.print(allInteger+ "  ");
                j++;
        }
}
//to get value/number of copies of the duplicate number/s
public static void getCopies(int[] Array) {
   for(int allCopies : Array) {
    copies[allCopies]++;
}

for(int k = 0; k < copies.length; k++) {
    if(copies[k] > 1) {
        System.out.print("\nValue " + k  + " : " +  copies[k] + " copies are detected");

    }
        }
        }
//remove duplicates
public static void removeDuplicates(int[] Array) {
 for(int removeCopies : Array) {
     duplicate[removeCopies]++;
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < duplicate.length; a++) {
        if(duplicate[a] >= 1) {
            System.out.print("\n"+a);

        }
            }
  }
 }
```

Example:
If we input :
1
2
3
3
4
5
-1

```
 The result of our program is : 1  2  3  3  4  5  -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 We want the result to be like: 1  2  3  3  4  5
```

We need your help guyz . practicing our programming 1 subject hope we could get some help here

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size.  If you want a list that can change size, try a List.

Comment: First lesson: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: `public class DELETE DUPLICATES` this doesn't compile!! Also follow Java convension first letter of class is capital not all

Answer (score 1):

You can do a following change just to print the required values:

```
for(int allInteger : maxInput)  
{
    if(allInteger == -1)
        break;

    System.out.print(allInteger+ "  ");
    j++;
}
```

but, better change would be to rethink your design and use of data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The maxInput array is of specified size that is 20, so it will have that no. of elements and prints the default value of int.

You can use List instead and check the size for max input and exit loop

Answer (score 0):

If you don't *need* to use an array, then a `Collection` has lots of advantages.  Let's use a `List`:

```
static int maxInputCount = 20;
static ArrayList<Integer> input= new ArrayList<>();
```

...

```
    for (int i = 0; i < maxInputCount; i++)
    {
            integer = scan.nextInt();
            if (integer == -1)
                break;
            input.add(integer);
    }
    for(int integer : input) {
            System.out.print(integer+ "  ");
    }
```